# Calling a python script from Linux cuases TypeError: file() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, linux, command-line-arguments

This script has worked before many time (I'm using it for the first time), so I believe the command in Linux is wrong somehow, even though I checked it many times.

The command needs to have the following structure:

```
python python_script_path.py -ccdb db_file.db -csvNameResolution input_csv_file.csv -csvManual another_input.csv -csvOut output_file.csv
```

**The python script**

```
# imports

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='usage:')
parser.add_argument('-ccdb','--ccdb', help='input: file to read from',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-csvNameResolution','--csvNameResolution',help='input: csv file - the output of the name resolution script', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-csvManual','--csvManual',help='input: csv file - manually prepared', required=True)
parser.add_argument('-csvOut','--csvOut',help='output: csv file which is the merge of the 2 inputs plus data queried', required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

myEncoding = 'utf-8'

sys.stdout = open(sys.stdout.fileno(), mode='w', encoding=myEncoding, buffering=1) # That's wehre the error occurs.
```

**The error message:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "python_script_path.py", line 39, in 
> sys.stdout = open(sys.stdout.fileno(), mode='w', encoding=myEncoding, buffering=1)
> TypeError: file() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

I don't understand what's the problem from this message. I looked at issues with similar error message but this error arises in various irrelevant scenarios.

Thanks!

Comment: That call to `open()` makes no sense - the first parameter is supposed to be a filename, but you're passing an integer.  The parameters look more like they were intended for `os.fdopen()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the code is written for Python 3, but you're invoking it with Python 2. In Python 3 the signature for open() changed to include various other parameters, including `encoding`, which this script uses. Try running:

```
python3 python_script_path.py -ccdb db_file.db -csvNameResolution input_csv_file.csv -csvManual another_input.csv -csvOut output_file.csv
```